# Is there a Lightroom feature for ranking images collaboratively?

Tags: lightroom, software, metadata

Say a photographer takes a bunch of photos and needs his teammates, who are geographically separated, to rank them so that the best of the best photos can be selected for post production. If it were just the photographer, he/she could just use Lightroom and use the star ratings to narrow down the options. How can a process like that be made collaborative? Is there a Lightroom feature that allow multiple people to rank images? Or is there a web service that can be used?

Comment: You could use something as mundane as Facebook. A private album can allow access only to desired people. "Likes" could be used (only 1 per photo) and/or the comments added could contain rankings and/or comments. There are probably API interfaces available that allow these to be read under program control.

Comment: Please elaborate  on what part should be collaborative: the rating, the editing or both?

Comment: Just rating. Want to know which photos to edit, and we want to be able to decide on those collaboratively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ligthroom CC** allows you [to create such galleries](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/how-to/share-photo-gallery.html):

1. create and login with your Adobe ID in LR
2. click the sync button left of the collection name that you want to share
3. go to https://lightroom.adobe.com/ and login there
4. you should now be able to share the gallery from the website via social media or direct link

---

There are third party plugins/templates available that let you create web galleries that allow user feedback. This is made for clients to provide feedback, but should work for colleagues just fine.

An example I found that works with **older versions of Lightroom** is the [TTG CE4 Client Response Gallery](http://shop.theturninggate.net/products/crg)

There are several other things available. They all seem to be templates for the web module to export a custom web gallery that has the desired functionality.

---

I'm not affiliated with any of the solutions mentioned.

Comment: But can other people "star" the images? It looks like they are limited to liking and commenting only.

Comment: Adobe has collaboration tools in LR and CC. Whether they would work for you I can't determine.

https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/collaboration.html

http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2014/11/lightroom-5-7-collaboration-features-and-the-lightroom-web-interface.html

https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/collaboration-faq.html

http://www.lightroomforums.net/showthread.php?25391-Collaboration-via-lightroom-sync-and-web

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like daminion.net (I do not work for this company). They have server product which allow collaborative work on digital assets.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGaiMmknj_A) is example video how to use filtering system